# Find and replace a line in a file

Tags: file, d, stdio, seek

My goal is to search the file line by line until it finds a variable declaration in the format of `varName = varValue`. Count up the bytes to the beginning of that line, then replace that line with the same `varName` but a new value.

This is a very simple configuration file handler, I'm writing it from scratch to avoid any dependencies. The reason I'm doing it this way and not just dumping a `string[string]` associative array is because I want to preserve comments. I also wish to refrain from reading the entire file into memory, as it has the potential to get large.

This is the code I have written, but nothing happens and the file remains unchanged when using `setVariable`.

```
import std.stdio: File;
import std.string: indexOf, strip, stripRight, split, startsWith;
import std.range: enumerate;

ptrdiff_t getVarPosition(File configFile, const string varName) {
    size_t countedBytes = 0;

    foreach (line, text; configFile.byLine().enumerate(1)) {
        if (text.strip().startsWith(varName))
            return countedBytes;

        countedBytes += text.length;
    }

    return -1;
}

void setVariable(File configFile, const string varName, const string varValue) {
    ptrdiff_t varPosition = getVarPosition(configFile, varName);

    if (varPosition == -1)
        return; // For now, just return. This variable doesn't exist.
        // Will handle this later, it needs to append to the bottom of the file.

    configFile.seek(varPosition);
    configFile.write(varName ~ " = " ~ varValue);
}
```

Comment: Try minimizing the your code to hone down to the problem.  I am not sure what your actual problem is.  Is `readConfig` really reliant to the problem?  Where is `File configFile` opened?  Show a sample config file and add `main` function that will shows how it is not working.  (btw, you are creating a dependency it is just a first party dependency :)  So, is the advantage of no third party library size or licensing? :) )

Answer (score 0):

There's a few parts of your code missing, which makes diagnosis hard. The most important question may be 'How do you open your config file?'. This code does what I expect it to:

```
unittest {
    auto f = File("foo.txt", "r+");
    setVariable(f, "var3", "foo");
    f.flush();
}
```

That is, it finds the line starting with "var3", and replaces part of the file with the new value. However, your `getVarPosition` function doesn't count newlines, so the offset is wrong. Also, consider what happens when the new `varValue` is a different length from the old value. If you have "var = hello world", and call `setVariable(f, "var", "bye")`, you'll end up with "var = byelo world". If it's longer than the existing value, it will overwrite the next variable(s).